# ActiveRecord Associations method for fetching associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models Brand, Category and Country in many-to-many association meaning that each brand may belong to many categories, each category may have many brands, each country may have many categories and brands I need to know a way to fetch categories that the brands were put into.

So far I have this:

```
@brands = Brand.includes(:categories)
```

which creates the association between brand and category and I am stuck. I don't know how to fetch the categories that the brands were put into. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of **has_and_belongs_to_many** association between models **Brand** and **Category**.

Rails guides does a great job in describing how it works.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HABTM relationship. Start from creating a new model `category` then create a new migration and named it `brands_categories` add references of both category and brand in your new migration. like `rails g migration brands_categories brand:references category:references`. Then permit `{:category_ids => []}, :categories_attributes => [:category]` in your brand_params. To add category in your brand view form something like this 
 
`<% Category.all.each do |cat| %>` 
  `<div class="checkbox">`
    `<label>`
    `<%= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][]", cat.id, @product.categories.include?(cat) %>`
 `<%= cat.category %>`
   `</label>`
  `</div>`
 `<% end %>`